# Devise redirects to root after I redirect to sign_in

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, devise, flash-message

I'm trying to add a new login condition to an app that uses Devise.

If a request comes from an IP that's not on my whitelist, I want to prevent the login and redirect back to the sign_in page with a flash message explaining that the login was from an outside IP.

The redirect works, but flash message that I set doesn't make it back to the sign_in page. I think this is because Devise is mysteriously adding another redirect in the redirect chain (which would kill the flash message because the flash message is only good for one request).

Here's what I'm doing: I check if the request ip is in my whitelist. If it isn't, I redirect to `/users/sign_in` and set the flash notice to show why the user can't login.

**This is where I get lost**... After the redirect to `/users/sign_in` occurs, the user mysteriously gets redirected to `/` which in turn redirects back to `/users/sign_in`.

That last redirect back to the sign_in page is one that we've defined ourselves for if the user isn't logged in. But the redirect back to the root URL is tripping me up. I haven't overridden the `new` action in the sessions_controller (which is where this mysterious redirect occurs...), so this is all Devise logic as far as I can tell.

Does anyone have a guess at what's going on, is there a devise config that would cause that redirect, or is there another way I should approach this whole thing?

In my sessions_controller

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  def create

    unless ip_whitelist.include?(request.remote_ip)
      redirect_to '/users/sign_in', :notice => "Cannot log in from this IP address."
      return
    end

    ...

  end
end
```

Comment: Have you tried to put your redirect logic as `before_filter`?

Comment: I just did and I didn't find any difference

Answer (score 1):

Per the Devise wiki, you could add an additional 'validation' for the user by adding an `active_for_authentication` method to your user model. Otherwise, the `devise_for` routing method does accept a `:constraints` option just like regular Rails routing constraints. Pack your whitelist logic into a class that responds to `matches?` and you should be good.